# AddThis pulling wrong Paragraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, sharing, addthis

I use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) to share my blog post. When I try to share my most recent post it pulls and displays the wrong paragraph on Facebook. I am unsure how to get it to pull the correct paragraph. Here is my AddThis code:

```
<div class="social"><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
<span class="addthis_separator">|</span>
<a class="addthis_button_compact" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?
v=250&amp;pubid=ra-">Share</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":
true};    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250
/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END --></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you must use OG Tags to tell Facebook what to use. Here is an example that solved my issue:

```
<meta content="Title of Page" property="og:title" />
<meta content="Blog Post" property="og:type" />
<meta content="Page URL" property="og:url" />
<meta content="Image to represent blog post." property="og:image" />
<meta content="Site Name" property="og:site_name" />
<meta content="Description of Page or Paragraph to display" 
               property="og:description" />
```

More Info can be found on [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and the [Open Graph Homepage](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 0):

## What Worked For Me

If you happen to be trying to use AddThis with UTM codes or other querystring variables, here's what finally worked for me.

As per [Sol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852328/1013405), use  [OpenGraph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) but then use the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to verify that Facebook cache has been refreshed and got all the proper meta tags in the page header correctly, then verify that there are no querystring UTMs/variables your AddThis sharing link to facebook. For my purposes, Index.html couldn't include any querystring variables or AddThis passed the URL incorrectly to Facebook. The only way that worked for me looks like this:

```
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.html" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

## What Failed For Me

When trying to use the below AddThis "data_track_addressbar" and "addthis_widget.js" modules for sharing, Facebook completely fail to pull the new OpenGraph Meta Tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```